# Concurrent INSERT thrown SQLException ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, insert

Scenario: Two users try to execute a "INSERT" query on the database concurrently but some times the SQLException is throwed:
*Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint... Details: key (id)=(1580) already exists.*
The id generation of entity is the type "Identity", so the id should be incremented by one when the second "INSERT" is called but probably the concurrent execution doesn't allow it. Any solutions? i'm using JPA with method **jpaApi.withTransaction()**, Hibernate and i tried to execute a manually flush after the save and i'm trying to change the type of generation id from "Identity" to "Sequence".
The problem is on the "INSERT" not "UPDATE".

Comment: Because you use identity for id.

Comment: i'm using generationType.IDENTITY. Do you think so that if i change generationType for creation id i can resolve my problem? what is the best generationType for the concurrency?

Comment: If you just resolve this problem use `uniqueidentifier` data type and generate `newid()` function. but this solution performance not good.

Comment: It seems the problem is solved after i modified the generationType to "SEQUENCE". Thanks for the help!